# Why does Braid forget that I bought the full version?

Tags: xbox-live-arcade, braid

I bought Braid for the Xbox 360 arcade about a year ago.  I wanted to play it again, but when I selected it from the game library and launched, the game thinks it's in trial mode.  How do I get Braid to remember that I bought the full version?

Comment: Have you changed or recovered your gamertag or anything like that?

Comment: No nothing like that.  This is a problem unique to Braid.  Every other arcade game I own works just fine.

Comment: I've actually seen that problem with a few other XBLA games as well. IIRC at least one game (which wasn't Braid, I don't have that one) would not unlock the full version even if you migrated the license to the new console.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This may be a known bug in Braid. If you take a look at [this post](http://braid-game.com/news/?p=321) on their official site (I realize it is from 2008, but the comments say this is still an unpatched bug), it mentions possible reasons why the game reverts to trial mode.

You can try redownloading the game, and it should recognize that you've already purchased it and unlock the full game on the new Xbox. If that doesn't work, some people have mentioned they have had success using the [License Migration Tool.](http://www.xbox.com/en-US/support/systemuse/xbox360/licensemigration/default.htm) So you could give that a shot.